# Error al intentar conectar con DB ORACLE

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data

tengo una simple aplicacion springboot 2.3.8 que intenta conectarse a una base ORACLE que ya existe y se freeza al arrancar en la siguiente línea:

```
2021-02-01 16:43:47.720  INFO 10796 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Mi application.properties es el siguiente:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.100.44:1521:XE
spring.datasource.username=GEMULA
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Si cambio a otra DB que está en otro servidor con otro usuario y password, todo funciona muy bien. Ahora, vuelvo a esta configuracion y no se conecta.
En cambio con esa misma configuracion, con el usuario SYSTEM, TARDA un par de minutos y al final se termina conectando.

Se les ocurre que puede estar pasando?...yo por SQL developer con ese usuario GEMULA y su password, me conecto y hago queries normalmente!...parece muy loco pero me ha tenido toda la tarde!. Gracias pro su ayuda!

Comment: ¿La instalación de la Express Edition es en el mismo equipo del Spring? ¿Cuál host tienes en SQLDeveloper?

Comment: @Sal no, es en otro equipo remoto de la misma red. Pero tengo ping y desde el sql developer me conecto normalmente. De hecho, como puse en el post, con el usuario SYSTEM, tarda un poquito, pero se conecta